# MongoDB sort by array size with large number of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an article collection which stores a list tags as following:

```
    {
       id: 1,
       title: "Sample title"
       tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"]
    }
```

In order to match articles to user's interest I use aggregation "match" and "setIntersection"
to count how many common tags between user's interest and articles tags then sort them to get best match.

```
  db.article.aggregate([
            {
                "$match": {                    
                    {"tags": {"$in": ["tags", ["tag1", ..., "tag100"]}}        
                }
            },    
            {
                "$project": {
                    "tags_match": {
                        "$setIntersection": ["tags", ["tag1", ..., "tag100"]]
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "tags_match_size": {
                        "$size": "$tags_match"
                    },
                }
            },
            {"$sort": {"tags_match_size" : 1}}
            { "$limit" : 40 }
            ]
            );
```

It works fine if I have few hundred documents in the article collection. Now I have around 1M articles, it takes around half an hour to finish.

I can't create index for "tags_match_size" to run faster as it is a new field in aggregate query.

How can I make the query run faster? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index for tags field. Index will work for only first $match.

Comment: Yes, I did create index for tags field. My query will work fast without sort "tags_match_size", but I want to get best matches that's why I need to sort "tags_match_size". Thank you